# How can we configure subdomain in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, embedded-tomcat-8

How can we configure subdomain in spring-boot? We use the embedded Tomcat server. Any idea of how to go ahead with it. I was told that we cannot use ngnix in spring-boot embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subdomain is on the DNS level and has nothing to do with Spring Boot.

You have to have a web server in front of the Spring Boot app like nginx or Apache that will act as a reverse proxy.

With nginx this could look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name subdomain.domain.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

If you only want to pass to one page:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/the_one_and_only_page.html;
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I need to show only a specific page on that subdomain maybe for example career page of a specific company. How do I manage that in the backend?

Comment: you can proxy_pass to only one page. I updated the anser

Comment: Thanks, Simon. It was very helpful to me. I had a query. My CSS and JSP files don't load. Can you suggest something about that?

Comment: Please open a new question with more details